# How to handle large data set of a API response in React Native

Tags: android, json, firebase, react-native, feed

I am currently working on a social app in React Native. At news feed screen I am getting 200 news data (including text + image + video + map + other activities in each feed like Facebook and other social media). It takes approx *5 second to execute API* and data size is *approx 2.70 MB*. But the issue is feed is not smooth like other social media. How can I improve feed smoothness and which side needs to improve -

1. API part or
2. React Native side. I am using **Flat list** to render data and State variable to store data.

Is there any technique in React to handle large data set? Please help..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview ] for rendering unlimited data and you can use onScroll pagination to avoid getting all the data at one time